# Aligning items of a list in the right side

Tags: css, list, alignment

I've been searching on how to align items of a list, verticaly, in the right side of a div.

I tried float,

```
li {
float: right;
}
```

But it makes the two items be in the right side but not on top of another as I intended.

What I got [on Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b57PP/), as you can see option1 and option2 are in the right side but not vertically aligned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CSS for your `li`, also add `clear:both;`. This prevents other objects from being to either side of your `li`. I tried it in your fiddle, and it works nicely

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp)

Comment: Thanks! - "8 more to go..."

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to remove float: right; and add text-align:right to UL check out eh jsfiddle link i provided to see the solution

```
//remove 
       li {
        float: right;
        }
   // and add 

    ul {

        text-align:right;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jspatel/F3XgY/

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a :

```
line-height:98px;
```

to your li class
So it will center your text with the ul height

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b57PP/1/)

Comment: That's not what I wanted - CDspace got it correctly, it was to put options on the right side of the ul and align them vertically (on top of another). Thanks tho